# Why does my bootstrap navbar break my Google Map in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, typescript, google-maps-api-3

I was successfully loading my google map, but the second I added a bootstrap navbar into my app.component template, I started receiving this error:

```
error_handler.js:54 EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Error in ./MainComponent class MainComponent - inline template:0:0 caused by: Cannot read property 'firstChild' of null.
```

My map id is matched with my documentGetElementById (which seems to be the common reason why people have this problem), so that's not the problem.  My map loads successfully as long as the navbar is not present.

## Main Component

```
<app-map></app-map>
```

## App Component

```
<app-navbar><app-navbar>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

## Map Template

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">

<!-- MAP -->
<div class="map-container col-xs-12">

        <div id="map">

        </div>

</div>


</div>
</div>
```

## Map Component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, RouterModule, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

declare var google: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-map',
  templateUrl: './map.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./map.component.css']
})

export class MapComponent implements OnInit {

  // google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['geochart']});
  //     google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawRegionsMap);

  constructor() { }


  ngOnInit() {

      let mapOptions = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(0,0),
            zoom: 2
        };

        let map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);

  }

}
```

## Nav Component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from "@angular/router";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-navbar',
  templateUrl: './navbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./navbar.component.css']
})
export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

## Nav Template

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">aether news</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <!-- <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">

    </div> -->
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Can you show your navbar component?

Comment: Ok - I just added the component and template.  thanks for taking a look